# Instance variable not assigned in Observable<> subscribe?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-in-memory-web-api

My games array is not being assigned when subscribing from Obersavable for some reason even though I for sure get the correct data (array) back from the server.

Here is **my game.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Game } from '../models/game';
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { NGXLogger } from 'ngx-logger';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GameService {
  private gamesUrl: string = 'api/games';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private logger: NGXLogger) { }

  getGames(): Observable<Game[]> {
    return this.http.get<Game[]>(this.gamesUrl);
  }

  getGame(id: number): Observable<Game> {
    const url: string = (`${this.gamesUrl}/${id}`);
    return this.http.get<Game>(url).pipe(tap(_ => this.logger.debug(`fetched game id=${id}`)), catchError(this.handleError<Game>(`getGame id=${id}`)));
  }

  log (operation: string) {
    console.log(operation);
  }

    /**
   * Handle Http operation that failed.
   * Let the app continue.
   * @param operation - name of the operation that failed
   * @param result - optional value to return as the observable result
   */
  private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      console.error(error); // log to console instead
      this.logger.debug(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }
}
```

And here is my **games.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Game } from '../../models/game';
import { GameService } from 'src/app/services/game.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-games',
  templateUrl: './games.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./games.component.css']
})
export class GamesComponent implements OnInit {
  games: Game[];

  constructor(private gameService: GameService) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getGames();
  }

  getGames(): void {
    this.gameService.getGames().subscribe(games => this.games = games);
    console.log(`games: ${this.games}`);
  }

  getGame(id: number): Observable<Game> {
    return this.gameService.getGame(id);
  }
}
```

As you can see, I am making a call to **getGames** in **games.component.ts** in which the **game.service.ts** is returning the response (Observable) back.

For some reason subscribe(games => this.games = games) does not work and I get 'undefined' for the games instance variable.
I for sure am getting the correct response as **subscribe(games => console.log(games))** does not show 'undefined' but an array of Objects instead.

Why isn't my instance variable being assigned?

**Edit:
Here is the output in console.log if I do subscribe(games => console.log(games))**

[image]

**Edit:
If I do the following the console log is correct. But if I reference the 'games' array outside of it, I get undefined again:**

```
  getGames(): void {
    this.gameService.getGames().subscribe((games) => {
      this.games = games;
      console.log(`games: ${this.games}`);
    });
    console.log(`all games: ${this.games}`); //this is undefined
  }
```

**EDIT: SOLVED - THANK YOU dileepkumar jami**
The solution was to remove the $ symbol and '| async' in my template:

```
<li *ngFor="let game of games$ | async">{{game.title}}</li>
```

to

```
<li *ngFor="let game of games">{{game.title}}</li>
```

Comment: What are you printing in the console.log? games or this.games

Comment: this.games which is undefined. If I do subscribe(games => console.log(games)) I get the correct array

Comment: Can you show us the output of console.log(games)

Comment: yes. I just edited this post with the link to the image (I can't embed an image yet since I'm a new user)

Comment: Just for testing, try removing the pipe part entirely from your service and Check. Also show us the Game interface

Comment: Is your question answered or you still need explanation?

Comment: I still need explanation. I don't have a Game interface. I wasn't sure if I needed one since the Angular tutorial doesn't have one.
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

Comment: I also updated my service and removed the pipe part. still no luck

Comment: Please have a look at my answer. I tried to give an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  1.    getGames(): void { 
  2.      this.gameService.getGames().subscribe((games) => {
  3.        this.games = games;
  4.        console.log(`games: ${this.games}`);
  5.      });
  6.      console.log(`all games: ${this.games}`); //this is undefined
  7. }
```

I numbered your lines of code.

As expected, `the line6` will return `undefined`.

The code from `line 2 to line 5` needs some time to be finished because it has an API call.

Because **Javascript** is asynchronous, it will not wait for the code (from line 2 to 5) to be finished.
 It starts executing the `line6`. But, by that time, `this.games` is `undefined`.

Even when you see in the browser console, you will see the output of the `line6` **first** and then you can see the `line4`

You can execute the below block to see how javascript works asynchronously

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log('Hello');
}

setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);
console.log('hi');
```

```html
As you can see, even though console.log('hi'); was written after setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);, hi would be printed first and then hello.

<p> So, javascript did not wait for the setTimeout(myFunction, 3000); to be finished and it started to execute the next line
</p>
```

**EDIT: SOLVED - THANK YOU dileepkumar jami**
The solution was to remove the $ symbol and '| async' in my template:

```
<li *ngFor="let game of games$ | async">{{game.title}}</li>
```

to

```
<li *ngFor="let game of games">{{game.title}}</li>
```

Comment: thank you this helps, I understand now. But I still don't understand why I can't get anything to print in my template. I have <li *ngFor="let game of games$ | async"> {{game.name}}</li> but nothing shows up

Comment: It should be `"let game of games"`. Remove the dollar symbol. Infact you dont need the `async` pipe as your are calling the subscribe

Comment: it worked by removing the dollar symbol and the '| async'. But why? In the following Angular tutorial it says to do this (at the very bottom of the page in hero-search.component.html)
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

Comment: Appending the dollar is just a convention.please see the component also in the tutorial. It is initialised with heroes$ only. Also, you dont need to use the async pipe because, in the tutorial, heroes$ is an observable which returns an array but it our case, games is just an array

Comment: wow. I totally missed that. And also the sentence in that tutorial: 'The AsyncPipe subscribes to an Observable automatically so you won't have to do so in the component class'

Comment: is the $ symbol just to avoid calling 'subscribe' or is there better reasons?

Comment: Yes, either you need to use the `async` pipe or call the `.subscribe()`

Comment: I tried upvoting but says I have reputation < 15. Can I note upvote or mark as the answer?

Comment: The $ is a convention that indicates heroes$ is an Observable, not an array.

Comment: You can upvote now. Later when your reputation is enough, it will show me

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
getGames(): void {
    this.gameService.getGames().subscribe(games => {
      this.games = games;
      console.log(`games: ${this.games}`);
    );   

}
```

Comment: strange. The log is correct in this subscribe. But if I reference the games array outside of it, it's undefined again.

Comment: Yes working as expected only, the console log is printed before your call to server is finished. It is the asynchronous behaviour of angular. If you really want to see the log, print it after some delay (setTimeout will help you).

Answer (score 0):

You can access the games array inside the subscribe arrow function, you are trying to console.log(`games: ${this.games}`); before your service returns response.

```
 this.gameService.getGames().subscribe((games) =>  {
   this.games = games;
   console.log(`games: ${this.games}`);
 });
```

Once the games property gets assigned you can access the value anywhere you want in the component. still you can't access the value, then you should check whether there's any error in your console.

**UPDATE**
Javascript is asynchronous, it wont wait for your service to complete to execute other codes, in your situation `console.log()` inside the `getGames` executes first before the subscription invoked. so that `this.games` value is `undefined`

```
getGames(): void {
    this.gameService.getGames().subscribe((games) => {
      this.games = games;
      console.log(`games: ${this.games}`);
    });
    console.log(`all games: ${this.games}`); //this is undefined
  }
```

Comment: This is similar to the other answer. The log is correct in your answer but if I reference the games array outside of it I get undefined again.

 this.gameService.getGames().subscribe((games) =>  {
   this.games = games;
   console.log(`games: ${this.games}`);
 });
console.log(`games: ${this.games}`); // undefined

Comment: is there any other error in your console? that might prevent the change detection in angular.

Comment: Javascript is asynchronous, you can't console.log(games: ${this.games}) next to the subscription. before assigning the property console.log executes first thats why the logged undefined

Comment: I see, if I print the 'games' array after the method call to 'getGames()' in ngOnInit() should it work there?

Comment: No it won't work, if you want to do anything you should do it inside the subscription function. You can create a separate method and call it inside the subscription.

Comment: How are they able to do it on Angular tutorial than? I went through this section quick so maybe I missed something?
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6